# OASIS VLSI layout files parser

Tags: parsing, vlsi, calibre

OASIS is a format for VLSI topology representation. I need a parser for the OASIS format, or maybe some documentation which will describe how this format is structured. I can't find any mentions of it in Google.

Is there an OASIS parser available out there, or at least some documentation on the file structure?

Comment: OASIS = Open Artwork System Interchange Standard. Unfortunately, the [open and interchange](http://ams.semi.org/ebusiness/standards/SEMIStandardDetail.aspx?ProductID=211&DownloadID=1882) parts do not appear to apply to the specification itself :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Cadence Virtuoso](http://www.cadence.com/products/cic/layout_suite/pages/default.aspx) will help you. The December 2013 release is stable, with all features added for OASIS.

Answer (score 6):

The OASIS file format is graph structure that defines the layout of the chip. Geometry in the file is divided into cells. Each cell can then be placed any number of times in different locations. The placements can be nested within other cells forming a DAG graph structure.

You can parse the `oas` file by writing a recursive descent parser and recreating the graph structure in memory.

The official specification for the `oas` format can be found [here](http://www.wrcad.com/oasis/oasis-3626-042303-draft.pdf).

Also, look at [KLayout source code](https://github.com/klayoutmatthias/klayout/blob/master/src/db/db/dbOASISReader.cc) for an example of how to write a parser for Oasis.